# What does the MaxOccurs property of Mono.GetOptions.OptionAttribute do?

Tags: command-line, mono

[Mono Documentation](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.GetOptions)

The documentation is missing here. What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the maximum number of times you can specify a particular option. For example, if MaxOptions is 2 for a particular option `-c`, something like `foo -c apple -c banana` is fine, but `foo -c apple -c banana -c coconut` is an error. If you leave `MaxOccurs` at 0, there is no limit to the number of times you can include an option.

Comment: If the option is a string, for example, which value gets used? The last one? Do you need to make it an array if you want to store all the values?

Comment: That part I'm not sure about. Try it and see! Note that `Mono.GetOptions` is somewhat unmaintained, which is why you're having issues finding good docs.